# Updating textarea does not get submitted in form

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

i am developing chrome extension in google calendar.
The description of the meeting is updated through jquery as shown below,

```
 <div class="ui-sch">
    <textarea id=":24" name=":24" class="textinput" style="overflow: hidden; resize: vertical;" rows="3" aria-labelledby=":13.descript-label">
    </textarea>
    </div>

 var el= document.getElementsByClassName("textinput");
for(i=0; i < el.length; i++) 
{ 
    if(el[i].type == "textarea")
    {   
        el[i].value="sample description";
    }
}
```

The content gets updated to the textarea as expected. but when we submit the form, the description is not submitted. Where as if we manually press enter after updating the content, the updated value from javascript is submitted.

I suspect, the data change in description box is binded to another variable. How to update the data change in desc to the form submission ?

**update :** 
Steps to simulate

1. open calender.google.com
2. click create meeting paste the above
3. javascript in your console. (observe the value of description field)
4. Now click save
   (the meeting description will not be saved if you open the meeting)
5. Now create a meeting and follow the above steps 1-3.
6. click on the description box and hit enter or any other character.
7. Save the meeting.
   (The description is saved to the meeting)

Comment: You might interest even more users by providing a complete small demo extension setup as downloadable source, since there is a huge community coding JS but not yet XUL.

Comment: updated the simulation steps.

Comment: Sounds like a race bug.

Comment: There is an extension doing the similar functionality, in that data is passed in form submission. I would like to know if there is need to trigger event for data change in the description box.

Comment: Try triggering "keyup" on the textarea before submitting and/or delaying submission with 'setTimeout'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example page, it seems as the Google API only recognizes changes when it listens a `change` event. You can simulate it by

```
el[i].dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked. Had been trying to figure out for past 2 days

Answer (score 0):

not verified, just a suggestion:

```
if(el[i].type == "textarea")
    {   
        el[i].value="sample description";
        el[i].onchange();
    }
```

Comment: sorry, it didn't work. el[i].onchange is not a function

Comment: `.trigger('change')`